# Split commit history by branch

Tags: git, git-log

I have a script, which gets all commits from selected repo for some period.

To do this, I use command:

```
 git --no-pager log --oneline --before 2018-07-20 --after 2018-07-18 --all --branches=* --remotes=*
```

But it gives output, not splited  by branch. How can I rewrite this command, to receive something like:

```
Branch development
MQP-1896 hdveyhbkehbkke
MQP-1895 fdghdfjfgj
Branch qa
MQP-1836 loejemgdsgsnlee
Branch feature
MQP-1833 fghdfghfghfh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find any thing in documentation where we could get commits listed like this, if anyone find this do comment.
You can write a bash script where you checkout all branches and git log on each of them

Sample (can be improved)

```
array=(`git branch`)
for i in "${array[@]}"
do :
echo $i
git --no-pager log $i --oneline --before 2018-07-20 --after 2018-07-18
done
```

write this code in file-name.sh 
and run it using `sh file-name.sh`

Comment: Why not save the current branch at the beginning and check it out at the end? Also you don't need to checkout a branch to list its commits — just pass the name of the branch to `git log`; example: `git log master`.

Comment: @phd thanks for the input, i am new to git, so still learning new things everyday, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

`git log` generally does not split output by branch.  You can use `--topo-order` to order the output in a way that should keep the commits from a branch together[1].  However, this still doesn't show the branch names.

```
git log --topo-order --oneline --before 2018-07-20 --after 2018-07-18 --all
```

(Note: The `branches=*` argument only means to include anything reachable from any branch (any ref under `refs/heads/`) in the output; this is redundant once you've specified `--all`, as is `remotes-*`.)

To get branch information, you could use a different formatting option, such as

```
git log --topo-order --format="%d %h %s" --before 2018-07-20 --after 2018-07-18 --all
```

This still isn't *exactly* what you asked for; the branch name will not get its own line.  Rather it appears in `()` at the beginning of the line for the commit the branch ref points to.  Two big caveats:

1) If the branch tip is omitted (e.g. because it's after the `--before` date) then the branch name won't be output

2) What's in the `()` is a list of all refs (branch or otherwise) that point directly to that commit

That's about as close as you can get with just a `git log` command.  You could put together a script to iterate over the branches and produce a log for each one.  This is similar to what jaspreet's answer proposes, but

1) I don't recommend using `git checkout` in the script, as the checkouts may lead to issues if you have local uncommitted changes.  Instead you could drive the script with something like `git for-each-ref refs/heads` and use `git log <branch-name>`

2) The script will end up making assumptions, so you'll have to decide what sort of assumptions are right for your repo and adjust the script accordingly.

---

[1] "commits from a branch" is speaking pretty loosely, or at least making some implicit assumptions.  In git commits aren't "part of a branch" as they might be in some other tools; a branch just points to one commit, and other commits might be reachable from that commit via parent pointers.  Being reachable by *first* parent pointers is roughly similar to being "part of a branch", but not all such commits were necessarily "part of the branch" at the time they were created - and in particular this definition includes the commits from before the branch was created on its "parent branch"[2].

[2] "parent branch" is speaking even more loosely; depending on your branching conventions it might or might not be a phrase that makes sense.